# Arduino sleep while digital pin is HIGH

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I want to make the Arduino Pro Mini run on a 3.7v (4.2v when fully charged) LI-Ion battery.

The project is I will use an IR sensor to control the relay. Based on the IR code received, I will toggle the relay digital output pin (HIGH or LOW). Initially, the arduino is set to deep sleep mode and when it receives an External Interrupt (pin 2 on pro-mini), it will process the IR code and switch on the relay.

```cpp
//Interrupts using Arduino
//Circuit Digest

#include "LowPower.h"
#include <IRremote.h>

volatile int output = LOW;
int i = 0;
#define RECV_PIN 2
volatile boolean sleepEnabled = true;

IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;

void setup()

{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  irrecv.enableIRIn();
  pinMode(RECV_PIN, INPUT);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(RECV_PIN), buttonPressed1, RISING); //  function for creating external interrupts at pin2 on Rising (LOW to HIGH)
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.println(i);
  ++i;
  delay(1000);
  output = LOW;
  digitalWrite(13, output);    //Turns LED ON or OFF depending upon output value
  if (sleepEnabled == true) {
    Serial.println("Going to sleep");
    delay(1000);
    LowPower.powerDown(SLEEP_FOREVER, ADC_OFF, BOD_OFF);
  }
  delay(500);
  readIR();

}

void buttonPressed1()           //ISR function excutes when push button at pinD2 is pressed
{
  sleepEnabled = false;
}

void readIR() {
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {
    Serial.println(results.value, HEX);

    if (results.value == 0xff4ab5) {
      sleepEnabled = true;
    }

  }
  irrecv.resume(); // Receive the next value
}
```

When the pro-mini goes back to sleep, everything is turned off.

How can I make the pro-mini consume minimal power while the relay pin is HIGH ?

Comment: Not really understanding your question: When the relay goes back to sleep, everything is turned off. ?? Do you mean whenthe proMini goess bach to deep sleep also the relay goes low and so everything attached to that relay is switched of?? Is the question how to toggle states of things attached tothe relay independent of the deep sleep of the proMini?? Please clarify so we could help you.

Comment: use a latching relay

Comment: @Codebreaker007 I modified the original post. The thing is that I want to make the pro-mini consume minimal power while the digital pin linked to the relay is HIGH. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Juraj I'm using a latching relay.. when the pro-mini goes to deep sleep power down mode, the relay pin becomes LOW.

Comment: let LOW be the usual state. only send a short pulse to switch the relay

Comment: @Juraj yeah, I agree with you that LOW will be the default state. The thing is that I'm concerned is power consumption. How can I make it operate at the lowest power consumption level ?

Comment: https://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11497